# How to express a rotation to describe the change of orientation between two quaternions?

Tags: linear-transformations, quaternions, programming, orientation

Please let me describe the following situation:
Having a quaternion q1 representing an orientation of an object in 3d space at time t=n and one other q2 at time t=n+1.
Is it possible to  calculate a description of what happend to the object with angles or rotation matrix?

The aim would be to reconstruct the rotation that happened between q1 and q2. So if i knew the angles around the objects axis (lets call them 2*Ψ,2*Θ,2*Φ) i could reconstruct q2 from q1 by multiplication with the quaternion I get from:

```
( cos ⁡ Ψ + k sin ⁡ Ψ ) ( cos ⁡ Θ + i sin ⁡ Θ ) ( cos ⁡ Φ + k sin ⁡ Φ ) 
= cos ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ cos ⁡ Φ − sin ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ sin ⁡ Φ  


= cos ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ cos ⁡ Φ − sin ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ sin ⁡ Φ 

    + i ( cos ⁡ Ψ sin ⁡ Θ cos ⁡ Φ + sin ⁡ Ψ sin ⁡ Θ sin ⁡ Φ ) 
    + j ( − cos ⁡ Ψ sin ⁡ Θ sin ⁡ Φ + sin ⁡ Ψ sin ⁡ Θ cos ⁡ Φ ) 
    + k ( sin ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ cos ⁡ Φ + cos ⁡ Ψ cos ⁡ Θ sin ⁡ Φ )
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a general nice formula to break down a rotation to break down an arbitrary rotation into rotations about $x,y,z$ axes. If there were such a formula gimbal locks would not happen, right? Yes, we can build any rotation using Givens rotations (like with Euler angles), but going the other way introduces discontinuities.

Comment: Anyway (looking at the title question). To reverse a rotation you use the conjugate quaternion: $\overline{q_2}=\overline{q_{rot}}\,\overline{q_1}$. To conjugate $q_{rot}$ you use $-\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ everywhere. Observe the change of order.

Comment: thanks Matti, Mauricio and Jyrki to answer my question or give me hints so far. I could do some calculations on the base of your advises. This actually brought me here to change the question and edit the description. This seems to be more close to what I actually want to know.

Comment: I don't think you should edit the question that much. Now the current answers are unrelated to the question. The purpose of questions is not only to help you, but also other people facing a similar issue and this edition will make this question a huge mess. I am not going to post a new answer because of that. Consider posting a new question and revert this one to previous state. Or just close it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a rotation quaternion $r = (\cos \theta/2, 0, 0, \sin \theta/2)$ and you multiply a general quaterion $p=(p_0, p_1, p_2,p_3)$ from the left (quaternion multiplication), you get a resulting quaternion $q$ so that
$$
q= 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \frac{\theta}{2} & 0  &0 &- \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
0 & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}  & \sin \frac{\theta}{2} & 0  \\
0 & -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} & \cos \frac{\theta}{2}   & 0  \\
\sin \frac{\theta}{2} & 0  &0 & \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \\
\end{array}
 \right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
p_0 \\ p_1 \\ p_2 \\p_3
\end{array}
\right]
$$
In order to solve for $\theta$, you can take for example the two middle rows. They just say that
$$
\begin{cases}
q_1 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 &+ \sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_2 \\
q_2 = -\sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 &+ \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
or
$$
\begin{cases}
q_1 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 &+ \sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_2 \\
q_2 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_2 &-\sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
You can multiply the first row by $p_1$ and the second row by $p_2$ to get
$$
\begin{cases}
q_1p_1 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_1^2 &+ \sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 p_2 \\
q_2 p_2 = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} p_2^2 &-\sin \frac{\theta}{2} p_1 p_2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
the sum of which is
$$
q_1 p_1 + q_2 p_2 = \left(p_1^2 + p_2^2 \right)\cos \frac{\theta}{2}
$$
I'm sure that from this, you can already solve for $\theta$.

Comment: thanks Matti, Mauricio and Jyrki to answer my question or give me hints so far. I could do some calculations on the base of your advises. This actually brought me here to  change the question and edit the description. This seems to be more close to what I actually want to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you know $q_2$ and $q_1$ such that

$$q_2 = q_1 q_z$$

And your goal is to solve for $q_z$ then you can simply multiply both sides by $\tilde q_1$ on the left so:

$$\tilde q_1 q_2 = \tilde q_1 q_1 q_z$$

$$\tilde q_1 q_2 = q_z$$

Where $\tilde q_1$ is the conjugate of $q_1$ so that $\tilde q_1 q_1 = 1$

Now, if you only know $q_2$ and want to recover $q_z$ you can do that as follows assumung the relationship $q_2 = q_1 q_z$ holds.

Multiply both sides by $z \tilde q_2$ on the right.

$$q_2 z \tilde q_2 = q_1 q_z z \tilde q_2$$

Where $z$ is the conventional "z-vector" $(0,0,1)$ embedded in a pure quaternion.

By definition, the reverse of $q_2$ can be written in terms of $q_1$ and $q_z$ as:

$$\tilde q_2 = \tilde q_z \tilde q_1$$

Replacing on previous equation we have:

$$q_2 z \tilde q_2 = q_1 q_z z \tilde q_z \tilde q_1$$

Since $z$ is an eigen-quaternion of $q_z$ so $z = q_z z \tilde q_z$ we arrive to:

$$q_2 z \tilde q_2 = q_1 z \tilde q_1$$

Which means that $q_1$ is the **twist-free** rotation component of $q_2$ (in the sense of the "Swing Twist Decomposition") when applied to $z$.

We define $z'$ as $z' = q_2 z \tilde q_2$, then $q_1$ can be recovered as:

$$q_1 = \frac{1 + z z'}{\sqrt{2 (1 + z \cdot z')}}$$

Which is a compact formula to find the unit quaternion aligning $z$ with $z'$ (sometimes known as the "half-way" solution).

Having $q_1$ we can recover $q_z$ as before as:

$$\tilde q_1 q_2 = q_z$$

Comment: thanks Matti, Mauricio and Jyrki to answer my question or give me hints so far. I could do some calculations on the base of your advises. This actually brought me here to change the question and edit the description. This seems to be more close to what I actually want to know.